# Recursion to Return a String

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an array of objects that are self referencing. I am trying to create a DDL (select drop down) with indentations to show the children appropriately.

Here is a screen shot of the "printed" results with console.log inside the function.

[image]

My function is based on recursion, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get it to return the string. If I create a variable outside the function I can tack on each `<option>` string, but I would prefer the function to be self contained.

Here is the function

```
function pedigree(currentTreeItem, spacing) {
    let treeItemChildren = getTreeItemChildrenById(currentTreeItem.ID);
    spacing += "-";

    treeItemChildren.forEach(function (treeItem) {
        // this should be returned by the function. currently the variable is declared outside.
        outsideHtml += '<option data=id="">' + spacing + folder.FolderName + "</option>";
        console.log(spacing + treeItem.Name); 

        pedigree(treeItem, spacing);
    });
}
```

Here is how it looks inside my select tag..

[image]

Comment: Read this question two times still not able to figure out the problem you are trying to explain. What exactly is the problem we are talking about here?

Comment: use `return treeItemChildren.flatMap` ... and `return pedigree(treeItem, spacing);`